# Getting an attribute directly from rails Class.find(:all) array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that Person.find(:all) returns an array of Person objects but is there somehow I can just get 'name' property of all people in the Person table?

Something like

```
        Person.find(:all).names
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use :select to retrieve only specific attributes.

```
Person.all(:select => :name)
```

Would give you person objects that only have the name attribute initialized.  Then you can map/collect that attribute to get the array of names.

Comment: One less step: `Person.all.collect(&:name)`

Comment: This is a nice approach, why do you have to use the `&` for `&:name`?

Comment: @Besi it's a shorthand way of doing `Person.all.collect { |p| p.name }` or the following three-liner:

`Person.all.collect do |p|`
`p.name`
`end`

This is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468624/444681