# What does Post.all.map(&:id) mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

```
Post.all.map(&:id)
```

will return

```
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ................]
```

What does `map(&:id)` mean? Especially the `&`.

Comment: thanks for closed as exact duplicate.  This question is a little hard for search. Sorry.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The `&` symbol is used to denote that the following argument should be treated as the block given to the method. That means that if it's not a Proc object yet, its `to_proc` method will be called to transform it into one.

Thus, your example results in something like

```
Post.all.map(&:id.to_proc)
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
Post.all.map { |x| x.id }
```

So it iterates over the collection returned by `Post.all` and builds up an array with the result of the `id` method called on every item.

This works because [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Symbol/to_proc) creates a Proc that takes an object and calls the method with the name of the symbol on it. It's mainly used for convenience, to save some typing.

Comment: This is not true. map(:id.to_proc) will throw an ArgumentError because map accepts no arguments. Passing a Proc as an argument is **not** the same as supplying a block. What `&` does is it turns a Proc into a block and if the operand is not a Proc it calls to_proc first and then turns the result into a block.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yeah, I forgot an `&` there.

Comment: Your first sentence should also read something like "`&x` is the same as `&x.to_proc`" - except that definition is infinitely recursive.

Comment: @sepp2k: I already removed that part.

Answer (score 6):

& means that you are passing a block

Post.all is the receiver of the method .map, and its block is being passed on

```
Post.all.map { |item| # do something }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map

It iterates over the array and create a lambda with symbol#to_proc

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Answer (score 3):

This takes all `Post` objects and creates an array with the `id` method being invoked on each one.

In other words, for ActiveRecord, this means that you are getting an array with the `id` attribute for all `Post` entities in your database.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Ruby trick, which relies on Ruby doing some dynamic type conversion. You can find an explanation of the [Symbol#to_proc trick here](https://pragdave.me/blog/2005/11/04/symboltoproc.html).